# Fragment with tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

i'm trying to create an Fragment with a tabs
first the main Activity has a bottom navigation with 
4 fragments. 1 of the fragments i want to make a tabs which will insert another Fragment so basically the Fragment has a tabs with Fragment

and i have Class MyPagerAdapter here is the java file

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View pop = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adopt,
            container, false);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) pop.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("DOGS"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("CATS"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(tabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) pop.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter.(getSupportFragmentManager().tablayout.getTabCount()) ;
    ViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    ViewPager.setOnPageListener(new tabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adopt,container,false);
}
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
}
```

The problem is that the GetSupportFragment doesn't funtioning
thank you for answering and Godbles

Comment: in your fragment tabs use `getChildFragmentManager` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager`

Comment: thank you sir! it work but why does the tablayout,,setOnPageListener, and TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener cannot resolve Godbless!

Comment: viewpager will be in lower case as defined in your reference

Comment: thank you sir 1 error remaining the tablayout after the getChildFragmentManagerr

Answer (score 0):

The definition of [getChildFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) is:

> Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment.

The definition of [getSupportFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()):

> Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this fragment's activity.